# Google Maps: Generate Web Embed codes with custom Markers and custom map stylings?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps Javascript API v3 to generate a very/heavily customised Map, in terms of Map Stylings and Markers. The Map is fully done and already put on the Website.

But when it comes to generating Embed Code portion, even after reading [it's Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start), as far as I understand, I can only generate the Embed code via `iframe` which basically doesn't allow me to render the Map with all the customizations I have done above. And it does not allow the custom markers as well.

Please advise how do I generate the HTML Embed Code for the Google Maps which would look exactly the same as fully customized Map put on the Website (with custom Markers and Stylings).

Answer (score 1):

The embed API is much more limiting. I assume you're doing that to reduce costs as the JS API is now expensive. The customizations you talk about are currently not available in the embed API, sadly.

Comment: Hi @Eran Goldin, thanks much for helping. I'm actually not trying to reduce cost. I just managed to hopped onto it's Embed API since I thought it was the correct one for Embed Codes (as it's name suggests). But if not, then what would be the best option to achieve it, please? Are you talking about embedding the whole original webpage via Iframe?

Comment: What is your use case? What are you trying to achieve? Is it embedding a map on a page you're building?

Comment: A map, plenty of custom Makers on it, and letting people (everyone) embed any of those "markers" in their whatever website they have.

Comment: So embedding the marker is essentially embedding your own code that lives on your server and has nothing to do with google maps?

Comment: Yes. That's why I'm seeking advice for whether I should be keep trying with Embed API (because I don't know it's limitations, etc). Or else with custom implementations.

Comment: Embed API will not allow map customizations like you want - you’ll need the JS API for that, or give up on most customizations

Answer (score 0):

The custom icons are currently not available for Google Maps Embed API, however, if you don't need such interactions with your Google Maps such as panning and zooming and just want to show a place with a custom marker, then you may try using [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/dev-guide#CustomIcons) as this supports the use of custom markers. If your use case requires users panning and zooming of the map, then the next suggestion would be [Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers) as this also supports the use of customer marker, however, this will require extra effort as this is not implemented via `iframe`unlike Embed API and Static Maps API. There are samples in the documentations provided as well.